# Multiply two int arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, operator-overloading

I have a type `BigInt` which stores large numbers as an array of digits (0-9) in a char array called privately `m_digitArray`.
I am overloading arithmetic and relational operators to help in development. However, I could not get the multiplicative operator `*=` to work for me. The code I posted works for **single digit** operations in `int * BigInt` only while I'd prefer it work for any length number and for all `int * BigInt`, `BigInt * int`, and especially `BigInt * BigInt` operations. Like it works for 6 * bigInt (with a value of 6) = 36; but not 11 * bigInt (with a value of 10).

### BigInt.cpp

Overloaded operator in question

```
BigInt BigInt::operator *= (const BigInt &rhs){
    int size = m_digitArraySize + rhs.getSize();
    int* C = new int[size];
    int s = size-1;

    for(int j= rhs.getSize() - 1; j >= 0; j--){
        int carry = 0;
        int shift = s;
        for(int i = m_digitArraySize - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            int m = getDigit(i) * rhs.getDigit(j);
            int sum = m + C[shift] + carry;
            int num = sum % 10;
            int c = sum/10;
            C[shift] = num;
            carry = c;
            shift--;
        }
        C[shift]= C[shift] + carry;            
        s--;            
    }
    reallocateArray(size);
    // for(int i = 0; i < size < ++i){
    //  m_digitArray[i] = '0' + C[i];
    // }
    // Nothing being returned, printing to debug
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        cout << C[i];
    }
    return *this;
}

// Overload the * operator for BigInt * BigInt operations
BigInt operator * (const BigInt &lhs, const BigInt &rhs){
    return BigInt(lhs) *= rhs;
}

// Overload the * operator for BigInt * int operations
BigInt operator * (const BigInt &lhs, int num){
    return BigInt(lhs) *= num;
}

// Overload the * operator for int * BigInt operations
BigInt operator * (int num, const BigInt &rhs){
    return BigInt(rhs) *= num;
}
```

Comment: This kind of an assignment operator typically returns an lvalue, not an rvalue; although if your class is Rule Of 3 compliant this isn't a major issue; but it's not clear from the limited code snippet whether this is the case. You're also leaking memory.

Comment: I recommend using `std::string` instead of character arrays.  The `std::string` can expand dynamically and you can access it like an array.

Comment: @Ðаn No, never said as much. Just help me debug what I have.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm still very new to C++ so I wasn't aware of the rule of 3, nor have I yet learned to spot and fix any leaking memory. However, I'll post the full code if you like.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I cannot use the string library, I am limited to char arrays only.

Comment: You can use this simple big integer class: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24969658/1162233

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well I was able to figure it out after some help. Here's the solution to the problem:

```
BigInt BigInt::operator *= (const BigInt &rhs){
// Create new BigInt to make changes non-destructively
BigInt numbers;
// A safe capacity size for the new BigInt
int size = m_digitArraySize + rhs.getSize();
// If either number is negative, set self to negative
if(!m_isPositive || !rhs.isPositive())
    numbers.initializeArray(size, false);
else
    numbers.initializeArray(size, true);
// Go through the multiplier
for(int i = 0; i < rhs.getSize(); ++i){
    int carry = 0;
    // Go through the multiplicand
    for(int j = 0; j < m_digitArraySize; ++j){
        // The product of multiplicand and multiplier plus the sum of the previous digits and the carry
        int product = (getDigit(j) * rhs.getDigit(i)) + numbers.getDigit(i + j) + carry;
        // Reset carry, necessary if the product is just a digit
        carry = 0;
        // Set carry to the tens digit
        carry = product / 10;
        // Set product to the units digit
        product = product % 10;
        // Save to the new BigInt
        numbers.setDigit(i +j, product);
    }
    // Inner loop cuts off near the end, continue the loop if there is a carry
    int nextDigit = i + m_digitArraySize;
    while(carry!=0){
        int new_value = numbers.getDigit(nextDigit) + carry;
        carry = 0;
        carry = new_value / 10;
        new_value = new_value % 10;
        numbers.setDigit(nextDigit, new_value);
        ++nextDigit;
    }
}
// Remove excess zeros
numbers.normalizeArray();
*this = numbers;

return *this;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have an error in the logic in that you're coding operator * as something that implements operator *= to do it's work. Your problem is that calling:

```
x = y * z
```

shouldn't change the value of "y". That's an unwanted side-effect. But if you define operator* for your BigInt as using *= to get the result, that's exactly what it would do. Also if you do that, then calling

```
x = z * y
```

will cause *different behaviour* to "x = y * z", because now z is changed instead of y, which violates basic commutative laws of mathematics.

*Start* with operator* and operator=, *then* construct operator *= by chaining together calls to those.

operator* should create a new BigInt, then multiply the two input BigInts (passed as "const BigInt&"), then return the newly-created BigInt. To optimize this, you look into move constructors. but it's not necessary.

operator= is your copy assignment function, it should be later built to use move semantics, but that's also not critical

Then after that you can use *= to combine the two other functions, by merely writing something simple such as:

```
BigInt BigInt::operator*=(const BigInt &rhs)
{
    (*this) = (*this) * rhs;
    return (*this);
}
```

Comment: afaik in principle it is perfeclty fine to implement `operator*` in terms of `operator*=` (if it is done correctly), but implementing `operator*=` in terms of `operator*` defeats the advantage of doing the operation in place. What would be the benefit of using your `operator*=` (apart from less typing which is a secondary issue imho)?

Comment: Operator * shouldn't change the left operand. That's not how math works. Operator *= can be implemented at first as * and = then optimized later.

Comment: if you use *= as the basis of * then you would need to copy the lhs to a temp. if the client provies x = y * z, y and z should not change, so you need to make a temp 't'. if you use *= then you need to copy y to t, then *= t with z. The copy operation was unnecessary, you should be able to initialize the t value with the result of the multiplication.